# Results of a hash function are just barely off

Tags: c, hash

I'm working on hashing in C.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE *nums;
    FILE *out;
    nums = fopen("data.txt", "r");
    out = fopen("results.txt", "w");

    int i, j, used = 0, unused = 0, collision = 0, longChain = 0, chain = 0,
        bucketCount, numKeys, temp = 0;
    float avgChain = 0;

    fscanf(nums, "%d", &bucketCount);
    fscanf(nums, "%d", &numKeys);

    int buckets[bucketCount];

    for(i = 0; i <= bucketCount; i++)
        buckets[i] = 0;
    for(i = 0; i <= numKeys; i++) {
        fscanf(nums, "%d", &temp);
        j = hash(temp, numKeys);
        buckets[j]++;   
    }

    for(i = 0; i <= bucketCount; i++) {
        if(buckets[i] != 0) {
            used++;
            collision = collision + (buckets[i] - 1);
        }
        if(longChain < buckets[i])
            longChain = buckets[i];
        chain = chain + buckets[i];
    }
    avgChain = (double)chain / (double)used;

    fprintf(out, "----------------------------------\n");
    fprintf(out, "H A S H  S T A T I S T I C S\n");
    fprintf(out, "----------------------------------\n");
    fprintf(out, "Bucket Count: %d\n", bucketCount);
    fprintf(out, "Key Count: %d\n", numKeys);
    fprintf(out, "Used Bucket Count: %d\n", used);
    fprintf(out, "Unused Bucket Count: %d\n", bucketCount - used);
    fprintf(out, "Collision Count: %d\n", collision);
    fprintf(out, "Longest Chain Length: %d\n", longChain);
    fprintf(out, "Average Chain Length: %0.3f\n", avgChain);

    fclose(nums);
    fclose(out);

    return 0;
}
```

and here is the hash function itself:

```
int hash(int i, int j) {
    int temp;
    temp = (i % j);
    return temp;
}
```

Now, we are given test data (which i can post if needed, but its rather large) and expected results for the data.
The expected results are as follows:

```
--------------------------------------
  H A S H I N G  S T A T I S T I C S 
--------------------------------------
Bucket count                      9997
Key count                        10000
Used bucket count                 6334
Unused (empty) bucket count       3663
Collision count                   3666
Longest chain length                 7
Average chain length             1.579
--------------------------------------
```

Now, my results obtained from the program when run are as follows:

```
--------------------------------------
  H A S H I N G  S T A T I S T I C S 
--------------------------------------
Bucket count                      9997
Key count                        10000
Used bucket count                 6336
Unused (empty) bucket count       3661
Collision count                   3662
Longest chain length                 7
Average chain length             1.578
--------------------------------------
```

I'm getting extremely frustrated, because I cannot seem to obtain the correct results unless I hard-code numbers into the project, which is not allowed.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `for(i = 0; i <= bucketCount; i++)` should probably be `for(i = 0; i < bucketCount; i++)` (same for `for(i = 0; i <= numKeys; i++)` ) BTW: for hashing (and bitfiddling), it is preferred to use *unsigned* types.

Comment: "my results obtained from the program" - were *not* produced by the program you listed. You have posted "something like" and want us to guess what is the same and what is different and what is a mistake..

Comment: @wildplasser could you elaborate on what you mean by unsigned types? Also, the changes you suggested don't fix the problem. It changes collision count to 3661 from 3662

Comment: Did you change *both* occurrences of `for(i = 0; i <= bucketCount; i++)`?

Comment: Sean: signed types behave strange/unwanted on modulo and bitops. Besides: the sizes *cannot* be negative. And also: the whole hashing-thing is intended to calculate an index/offset. Do you really want to allow a negative offset/index?

Comment: If you didn't understand the answer below, you should change your hash to: `j = hash(temp, bucketCount)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your program output:

```
Bucket count                      9997
Key count                        10000
```

so the array is

```
int buckets[9997];
```

however the `hash()` function returns

```
data % 10000;
```

so if it is called thus

```
j = hash(9999, 10000);
```

the array will be indexed as

```
buckets[9999]++;
```

which is out of range.

Comment: thank you very much, this was exactly the problem. Everything works great now.